# What does Far mean in c?

Tags: c, pointers

```
const struct sockaddr FAR* name,
```

Comment: It means I've got Bill Gates on hold and he wants to talk to you about getting his "640k will be enough for anyone" back from the 1980s.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's an old extension from the era of segmented memory architectures. It basically means "this is a pointer that needs to be able to point at any address, not just things in the same segment as the code using it".

See more or on the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Far_pointer).

Comment: pretty much, unless you NEED to write 16 bit code for some funny reason (which is really really really really rare). Useless for normal people.

Comment: On some other platforms near and far pointer may appear (not exactly with the same meaning), so if you'll do crosscompiling you may have deal with it.

Comment: @ollydbg - for current-day x86 PC platforms and applications, yes.  For other platforms, like single-chip embedded ones, no.

Comment: Yes, it's completely useless today and never was part of the language.

Comment: @R..: It's not part of C, but it's a compiler directive that is occasionally *required* for the vast majority of computers in the world today (hint hint, they're not x86 or ARMs).

Comment: @Nick: I'm not sure which you mean, but any good compiler for backwards segmented architectures will have a "huge" memory model you can choose to make all pointers large enough to hold any address. That's what I always used back when writing code for DOS/Win16.

Comment: @Nick:  In this example `FAR` is in fact most probably a *macro* not a directive, and in Win32 is is an empty macro at that.

Comment: C compilers for the 8051 tend to use `near` and `far` (and a host of other platform-specific storage classes like `data`/`xdata`/`pdata`/`code`, `bit`, `sbit`, etc.).

Answer (score 4):

`far` doesn't mean anything in C.  Check out the [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) [PDF] and see if you can find mention of far pointers.  Far pointers were an extension added to compilers targeting the 8086/80286 architectures to provide support for the segmented memory model.

Answer (score 3):

If does *nothing* unless you happen to be using a 16 bit x86 compiler.

If you look in the Win32 header WinDef.h (in Visual Studio, simply right-click the word FAR in the source and select "Go to Definition", you will see that it is a macro defined as `far`, which in turn is also a macro defined as nothing at all!

It is only there to allow the compilation of legacy Win16 source as Win32.  In 16 bit x86 compilers, `far` was a compiler extension keyword to support seg::offset pointers which resolve to a 20bit address (16 bit x86 only had a 1Mb address space!).  They are distinct from 16 bit `near` pointers which comprised only the ::offset from the current segment.

Comment: Several other platforms also have near and far pointers. AVR for example.

Comment: @Vovanium:  Can you provide a citation?  The GNU AVR compiler certainly does not support `far` or `near` keywords. The GNU compiler for Toshiba's MeP has `near` and `far` however, but not for the same architectural reason as x86 Real Mode.  So yes, some architectures still require extensions to address different memory spaces; not just `near` and `far`.  Harvard architectures and DSPs typically require extensions.

Comment: IAR have tiny, near, far and huge storage specifiers (look http://supp.iar.com/FilesPublic/SUPPORT/000373/memoryusage.pdf ) And yes, pointer size specifiers may not be the same as x86 ones.

Comment: @Vovanium: Thanks for taking the time.  I've never needed to use an AVR with enough memory to need a far pointer!  That's what ARM is for! ;)

Comment: Clifford: Look, ATXMEGAs are fat and fast for large applications. So if someone is loving AVR it's the choice. But I prefer 32 bit MCUs too. :)